# CodeIgniter file upload change file name inside looping

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

The case is I have 3 file inputs. Each name attribute for them are `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`

Then inside my controller, I use `switch case` function for I want to rename the file.

`file1` = 'label'
`file2` = 'meter'
`file3` = 'rumah'

```
for ($n=1; $n<=3; $n++) {
    if (empty($_FILES["file$n"]['name'])) continue;

    $filext = pathinfo($_FILES["file$n"]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    switch($n) {
        case 1: $namae = 'label'; break;
        case 2: $namae = 'meter'; break;
        case 3: $namae = 'rumah'; break;
    }

    $config['upload_path']      = $upload_path;
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = 1024 * 20;
    $config['file_name']        = $namae;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file$n")) {
        ${"photo$n"."_upload"} = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        ${"photo$n"."_upload"} = $this->upload->data();
        $this->model->simpan_foto($id_survei,$namae,${"photo$n"."_upload"}['file_name']);
    }
}
```

But it didn't work! All 3 of the files are named with 'label', so it's label.png, label1.png, label2.png (because I not use `$config['overwrite']`)

How to accomplish this?

Comment: where is I haven't added any condition? I've already typed `case 1: ...`,  `case 2: ...`,  `case 3: ...` there. :/

Comment: I've read your code carefully but still didn't found something wrong. Did you try to `echo $namae` inside the loop (after switch-case) and see what happen?

Comment: I have the line where I pass `$namae` to save it to database, at line: `$this->model->simpan_foto($id_survei,$namae,${"photo$n"."_upload"}['file_name']);`, the `$namae` value was indeed changed according to my `switch case`. So I guess the problem is on `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` line, where `$config[]` is not updating to the library ._.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only three file than try this code....

```
for ($n=1; $n<=3; $n++) {
    if (empty($_FILES["file$n"]['name'])) continue;

    $filext = pathinfo($_FILES["file$n"]['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($n==1){
     $namae = 'label';
     }
     if($n==2){
     $namae = 'meter';
     }
     if($n==3){
     $namae = 'rumah';
    }

    $config['upload_path']      = $upload_path;
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']         = 1024 * 20;
    $config['file_name']        = $namae;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file$n")) {
        ${"photo$n"."_upload"} = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        ${"photo$n"."_upload"} = $this->upload->data();
        $this->model->simpan_foto($id_survei,$namae,${"photo$n"."_upload"}['file_name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Could you explain to me what's exactly the differences between your code and mine? Because I'm not seeing any difference there except you changed the `switch case` with `if else` :/

Comment: sometimes switch case won't work i have face that issue in some task so